# Stop Netbeans 8.1 from ignoring the `vendor` directory

Tags: netbeans, composer-php, gitignore, ignore, vendor

For PHP projects, Netbeans 8.1 seems to always ignore the `vendor` directory in Git repositories, regardless of the content of any `.gitignore` file or the project `ignore folders` settings.

Is it possible to stop Netbeans 8.1 from always ignoring the `vendor` directory?

For instance for projects which have a `vendor` directory that has nothing to do with Composer or for projects where all files required to run the code should be included in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `vendor` is consider as a non-shareable folder, [as `build` and `dist` would be in a J2SE project](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208939).
Try, as in [issue 194650](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194650):

```
Tools > Misc > Versioning > Git. Unselect 'Permanently ignore not-sharable files'
```

Also, check you `<yourRepo>/.git/info/exclude file`: it it exists, it might include `vendor/`

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970259/stop-netbeans-8-1-from-ignoring-the-vendor-directory/35970495?noredirect=1#comment60038361_35970495) by [the OP Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951064/martijn):

> Turns out this is a new feature in NB 8.1.
>   I **[filed a bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258345)** which was accepted and the next update should have options for disabling this feature for composer, bower and npm folders.

---

That was implemented a [few day later in March 2016](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=258345#c7): "`Ignore vendor directory from versioning`" ([changeset 681ac116d63b](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/rev/681ac116d63b))

> Please, uncheck it (available for Bower, npm and Composer) and ideally restart the IDE.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid neither fixes this. The option mentioned (since moved to `Tools > Options > Team > Versioning > Git > Permanently ignore non-sharable folders`) didn't make any difference (nor should it; this folder is not something Git should know about). I also don't have a `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: Then try a git add --force vendor/afile or even git add --force vendor

Comment: That should at least force the tracking of the vendor content

Comment: Adding the files outside Netbeans is no problem at all. Git itself doesn't ignore the `vendor` folder, it treats it just like any other directory (as it should). Netbeans 8.1's implementation of Git does.

Comment: Turns out this is a new feature in NB 8.1. I filed a bug report which was accepted and the next update should have options for disabling this feature for composer, bower and npm folders.

Comment: @Martijn Great! Do you have a link to that bug report?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Link to bug report is here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258345

Comment: @Martijn Thank you. I have included your comment (and your link) in the answer for more visibility

Answer (score 5):

I've found excep ingoring in git settings you also need turn off option "Ignore `vendor` folder from versioning" here sceen [image]

Answer (score 0):

As @webmak10 mentioned, you need to uncheck "ignore vendor" in 
`PHP -> Framework -> Composer options.`

Please note that restart is necessary to take into account this parameter.

*Tested with netbeans 11.*